# How to retrieve escaped quotes in mongodb + php mongoclient

Tags: php, mongodb

I have inserted escaped quotes into mongod

```
db.taskQueue.find({},{'details.AddRecords':1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f276242798710c3fbfe8f2"), "details" : { "AddRecords" : [ { "recordType" : "txt", "value" : "\"test with quotes/\"", "subdomain" : null } ] } }
```

So that looks good, but using mongoclient, the data comes out as

```
[value] => "test with quotes/"
```

I can't find anything about this, and that's coming directly out of the mongcursor I've tried with the older mongoclient, and the newer  MongoDB\Client

Comment: I have tried with Java driver. It comes up with "\"test with quotes/\"" as expected.

Comment: yeah i suspect it's the php drive, which is unfortunate..

Comment: not that anyone answers questions on here anymore, but in case they do. it  seems the newer mongodb pecl driver fixes this, the older 'mongo' driver has the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not that anyone answers questions on here anymore, but in case they do. it seems the newer mongodb pecl driver fixes this, the older 'mongo' driver has the issue. – Monsters X just now   edit